# How to avoid Firebase fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode7.3, forced-unwrapping

I am trying to read from Firebase and set the label to the value I get

This is what the top of my ViewController class looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ProfileTabViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
var userName = "userName"
```

I have a Firebase Reference at

```
var currentUserName = Firebase(url: "https://buzzmovieios.firebaseio.com/users/884962b7-9fd8-49db-b172-1ad7cb1414f4/Name")
```

The random string is the uid returned by Firebase.

I am trying to get the user name in the viewDidAppear() method:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    print(currentUserName)
    currentUserName.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in
        let name = snap.value as! String
        self.nameLabel.text = name
    }

}
```

the let name line works fine.

```
print(name)
```

This line:

```
self.nameLabel.text = name
```

causes:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

I've tried

```
let name = snap.value as? String
```

and it doesn't work.

This is what my Firebase looks like:

[image: FIREBASE]

```
buzzmovieios
    users
      --884962b7-9fd8-49db-b172-1ad7cb1414f4
               Major: CS
               Name: Shawn
      --8880069d-1944-493d-8246-8119fc4bfc81
```

and so on.

How can I avoid this unwrapping error? Thanks!

Note: I'm running XCode 7.3

Comment: Same thing: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: please check your outlet is connected properly or not

Comment: I don't believe it... deleting and adding a new label worked. Thank you! URGH!

Comment: Yes please do so. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please use if let to unwrap optionals like

```
  if let name = snap.value as? String{   
         self.nameLabel.text = name
  }
```

and also check that your outlets connected properly otherwise it crashed..