# Getting an error when using Segmented UI on xcode

Tags: firebase

I watched a tutorial on youtube and I did exaclty like the tutor said.I even copied his code from the source file he provided and I get an error...but if I run his project then it works.

Why these things happens?

I have a segmented component and when I change it from login to register this code runs:

```
@IBAction func signinSelectorChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    // Flip the boolean
    isSignIn = !isSignIn

    // Check the bool and set the button and labels
    if isSignIn {
        signinLabel.text = "Sign In"
        loginButton.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        signinLabel.text = "Register"
        loginButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    }

}
```

when I switch I get this error message :

> 2017-04-27 21:30:34.932 FIREBASE - Read and Write[38283]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

what is wrong?

thank you

Comment: You might want consider changing the question title to something relevant if you want the best chance of getting an answer. You said "when I change it" but have not explained how you are changing the code - examples of before and after you've changed it would be useful. As we don't have any details about the tutorial, it would help to add a description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564178/how-to-avoid-firebase-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-op